# Sending WNS toast via PHP

Tags: php, curl, wns

I am using a Javascript app in Visual studio 2015. That app requests a channelURL using the Windows Notification Service (WNS) and saves that on the server's database. In PHP with cURL I can request an access token, but when I don't know how to send an actual push notification (toast) to my channelURL. Does anyone got a clue?

Answer (score 2):

Is your question about how to format a toast? You can read up on the documentation here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh761493.aspx

If your question is more generally about how to make a request to WNS to push a notification, follow the steps here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh868252.aspx